# I can't delete or hide Displaying all results in woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Adding to CSS did nothing, adding snippets from php below also.

````
CSS:
.woocommerce-result-count {
display: none;
}```

Snippets:
```removeaction ('woocommercebeforeshoploop', 'woocommerceresultcount', 20);```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override woocommerce default styling like so:

```
.archive .woocommerce-result-count {
    display: none !important;
}
```